# Regex replace found match with static word

Tags: c#, regex

My input is:

```
Foo 12;
Foo 5534;
Foo 1;
```

I want to replace

`Foo (\d+?);` to `Foo NUM;`

In result it will be:

```
Foo NUM;
Foo NUM;
Foo NUM;
```

My pattern is:

```
Regex.Replace(line, "Foo (\d+?);", "NUM");
```

But that seem not work. What's wrong there?

Comment: If you want to replace numbers with `NUM` then use `(?<=Foo )\d+(?=;)` to replace with `NUM`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are matching `Foo (\d+?);` and replacing that match with `NUM` which will be the literal result. But what you want to keep in the replacement is not the digits but `FOO`

You could do the replacement the other way around using a capturing group for Foo and using that capturing group in the replacement.

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"(Foo) \d+;", "$1 NUM;")
```

You can omit making the `\d+` non greedy using the questionmark.

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28Foo%29+%5cd%2b%3b&i=Foo+12%3b%0d%0aFoo+5534%3b%0d%0aFoo+1%3b&r=%241+NUM%3b) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/mk4vGL)

[image]

Comment: just added this (Foo)\\s*\\d+; so we don't need to define space manually I think so

Answer (score 1):

**Solution without regex**

If your last word is **always** number and you want to replace it with "NUM",
then you can do it something like

```
line.Replace(line.Split(' ').Last(), "NUM");
```

POC: [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/x5k9YE)

Answer (score 0):

use this regex:

```
Regex.Replace(line, @"Foo (\d+?);", "NUM;");
```

you simply need `@` before the regex.
Here you can test your regexes:

[regex test](https://regex101.com/)